# python define range of colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, range, colorbar, contourf

I made a contourplot and as default it sets eight different colors in the range of -150 to 250. 
But I want to increase the number of colors, so the resolution of the colorbar.

I tried some things (for example like in the code sample below) but nothing worked. So maybe someone can help me with this?

Here is a code sample:

```
m2 = Basemap(projection='kav7',lon_0=0)
m2.drawcoastlines(linewidth=1.)
m2.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,99.,30.))
m2.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,60.))

v = np.linspace(-150., 250., 10., endpoint=True)
cs = m2.contourf(lon,lat,sshf_mean,latlon=True,cmap=cm.jet)
cbar = m2.colorbar(cs,location='bottom',pad="5%",ticks=v)
```

So at the end there should be the colorbar with 40 different colors instead of 8.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contourf` has two options to set the amount of levels; you can either set them manually, or let matplotlib chose `N` levels. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
values = np.random.random(100).reshape((10,10))

pl.figure()
pl.subplot(131)
pl.contourf(x, y, values)
pl.colorbar()

pl.subplot(132)
# Automatically chose 100 levels:
pl.contourf(x, y, values, 100)
pl.colorbar()

pl.subplot(133)
# Manually specify 20 levels:
levels = np.linspace(0,1,20)
pl.contourf(x, y, values, levels)
pl.colorbar()
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you very much! :)